# REACT-Display content of my json file but get only the header

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, react-hooks, data-extraction

I can't display the content of my json file in my table. I get the headers but nothing in cells.

Here is my code:

```
import Table from './Table'
import Menu from "./menus.json"


export default function Display() {
    const [menu, setMenu] = useState([Menu]);


    const data = useMemo(() => [
        {
            Header: 'Id',
            accessor: menu.id,
        },
        {
            Header: 'Title',
            accessor: menu.title,
        },
        {
            Header: 'Invited',
            accessor: menu.invited.name,
        },
        {
            Header: 'Price',
            accessor: menu.price,
        },
    ], [])
    return (

        <Table data={menu} columns={normalizeData(data.result)}>
    )

}
```

Just before the return i tried  an Object.keys(data).map((key) => ({id: key,})); but doesn't work.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: The `menu` state is an array, so `menu.id`, etc... will be undefined. What is the purpose of this `accessor` property? Is it supposed to be the property key to use to access *that* property of each menu item object in the `Table` component? Can we see this `Table` component and what it's doing with the `data` prop? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Sure here the Table compo: https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-bird-0g6dfb?file=/src/Display.jsx

Comment: Sandbox appears to be incomplete. It's missing some component files.

Comment: I'll add them if you want, but I pretty sure, it's not my Table the issue because, I already use it and it works fine. So, i'll I have a bunch of files to add

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON data is an object:

```
{
  "menus": [
    {
      "id": "Menu1",
      "title": "Creamy pea soup topped with melted cheese and sourdough croutons.",
      "price": 4,
      "invited": [
        {
          "name": "Jose Luis",
          "location": "LA"
        },
        {
          "name": "Smith",
          "location": "New York"
        },
      ],    
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

...

```
import JsonData from "./menus.json";

...

const { menus } = JsonData;
```

The `accessor` property isn't correct.

[Column Options](https://react-table.tanstack.com/docs/api/useTable#column-options)

- `accessor: String | Function(originalRow, rowIndex) => any`

  - **Required**
  - This string/function is used to build the data model for your column.
  - The data returned by an accessor should be **primitive** and sortable.
  - If a string is passed, the column's value will be looked up on the original row via that key, eg. If your column's accessor is `firstName` then its value would be read from `row['firstName']`. You can also specify deeply nested values with accessors like `info.hobbies` or even `address[0].street`
  - If a function is passed, the column's value will be looked up on the original row using this accessor function, eg. If your column's accessor is `row => row.firstName`, then its value would be determined by passing the row to this function and using the resulting value.
  - Technically speaking, this field isn't required if you have a unique id for a column. This is used for things like expander or row selection columns. **Warning**: Only omit `accessor` if you really know what you're doing.

Use stingified accessors

```
const data = useMemo(
  () => [
    {
      Header: "Id",
      accessor: "id"
    },
    {
      Header: "Title",
      accessor: "title"
    },
    {
      Header: "Invited",
      accessor: "invited[0].name" // because invited is an array
    },
    {
      Header: "Price",
      accessor: "price"
    }
  ],
  []
);
```

Or use a function

```
const data = useMemo(
  () => [
    {
      Header: "Id",
      accessor: row => row.id
    },
    {
      Header: "Title",
      accessor: row => row.title
    },
    {
      Header: "Invited",
      accessor: row => row.invited[0].name
    },
    {
      Header: "Price",
      accessor: row => row.price
    }
  ],
  []
);
```

[image: Edit react-display-content-of-my-json-file-but-get-only-the-header]

Answer (score 1):

```
import { menus } from "./menus.json";
```

Maybe you try to do this?

Comment: Do I have to modify by `const [menu, setMenu] = useState([menus]);`  ? and the rest is ok ?

Comment: Doesn't work :  I tried to` import * as { menus } from "../menus.json"` but doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be Menu.menus or you can destructure it to:

```
const {menus} = Menu
```

Comment: hi, when I used this syntax, I have several rows but all empty (before I have no rows)